# Trying to get Grails 1.3.5 working with JNDI connections not using GORM

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm trying to configure a Grails 1.3.5 app to work with the default tomcat instance built into Grails using JNDI.  The app doesn't use GORM.  I want to connect to the datasources myself.  I'm using a library for the model layer we use for other apps.

**resources.xml**

As well as the bean headers I have:

```
<import resource="data.xml" />
<import resource="service.xml" />
```

In **data.xml** I have:

```
<bean id="subjectJdbcDao"
    class="uk.co.xxx.dao.subjects.SubjectJdbcDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jobDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In **resources.groovy** I have:

```
def jobDataSource = new org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@berlin:1521:casdev','cso','job')
   grails.naming.entries = ['jdbc/job':jobDataSource]
```

I've tried everything but can't seem to get the data.xml file to find the jndi data sources.  I keep getting this error:

```
    2010-11-22 17:09:38,855 ERROR [context.GrailsContextLoader] Error executing bootstraps: Error 
creating bean with name 'SubjectJdbcDao' defined in URL [file:grails-app/conf/spring/data.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 
'jobDataSource' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'SubjectJdbcDao' defined in URL [file:grails-app/conf/spring/data.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'jobDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobDataSource' is 
defined
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
```

Does anyone know where I should put my datasource definitions so that they get picked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datasource should be an instance of a org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.

If you run the tomcat embedded in grails, you will need to simulate your JNDI datasource by adding the following entry in Config.groovy:

```
grails.naming.entries = ['jdbc/jobDataSource': [
    type: "javax.sql.DataSource", //required
    auth: "Container", // optional
    description: "Data source for ...",
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@berlin:1521:casdev",
    username: "cso",
    password: "job",
    driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
    maxActive: "8", //and so on
    maxIdle: "4"
  ]
]
```

If you want to run your application as a war and need an actual JNDI Datasource deployed and managed by tomcat, you need to create a tomcat context for your application:

If your application is jobapp.war, you must put a jobapp.xml under TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/jobapp.xml

This jobapp.xml should contain the following:

```
<Context path="/jobapp">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/jobDataSource"
    auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="cso"
    password="job"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@berlin:1521:casdev""
    defaultAutoCommit="false"
    <!--
        ... other parameters
    !-->     
          />
```

I believe this should do the trick
(make sure your drivers are available to your tomcat installation if you run it as a war)

Regards,

Vincent Giguère